# ng2-charts bar graph not displaying data/graph labels

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I structured a horizontal bar graph using ng2-charts in angular2 but i am not sure why i am not seeing graph data nor am i seeing any errors in my console.

HTML:

```
<canvas baseChart [data]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

Component:

```
  result: Iresult[] = [];

  barChartLabels: string[] =[];
  barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartLegend: boolean = true;
  barChartData: any[] = [];

  barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };
  barChartLabels: string[] =[];
  barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartLegend: boolean = true;
  barChartData: any[] = [];

getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.result = data;
        this.barChartLabels = this.result.map(item => item.label);
        console.log(this.barChartLabels); // RESULT: ["test 1", "test 2"]
        this.barChartData = this.result.map(item => item.data);
        console.log(this.barChartData); // RESULT: [25, 55]
      },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        console.log(this.barChartLabels); // RESULT: []
        console.log(this.barChartData); // RESULT: []
  }
```

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "test 1",
    "data": 25
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "label": "test 2",
    "data": 55
  }
]
```

Service File:

```
getData(): Observable<IChartData[]>{
        return this._http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ywavt')
            .map((res:Response) => <IChartData[]> res.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))) //DEBUG USE
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

//Console do result: All: [{"id":5,"label":"test 1","data":25},{"id":6,"label":"test 2","data":55}]
```

Interface class

```
export interface IChartData {
    id: number;
    label: string;
    data: any;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a Plunker of what i have so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/0GyFTkuqF7m8JhUKK6Kl?p=preview

Labels are not being displayed but a colored horizontal bar is not being positioned properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### UPDATE 2


As the problem is still there when initializing the chart data async in `subscribe`, a working solution is to use a *loading flag* combined with `*ngIf` to wait for the data from the service to be loaded before initializing the chart.

That would look like this:

Template:

```
<canvas *ngIf="loaded" baseChart [data]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Component:

```
loaded = false;

getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.resultData = data;
      this.barChartLabels = this.resultData.map(item => item.label);
      this.barChartData = this.resultData.map(item => item.data);
      this.loaded = true;
    }
}
```

Here is a [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xr6xs6PmaF9iQ6DsRnHT?p=preview)

### UPDATE 1


According to your comment, this helped with displaying the data, but the labels are still not showing up. From the code you have provided, it's really hard to know why, but it's probably something wrong with your data. Can you log the `barChartData` and `barCharLabels` so I can have a look at it?

Here is a working plunker for your example, but with hard-coded data: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hrNrzoaffyJVHyujlMQQ?p=preview)

### ORIGINAL

The ng2-chart is using `ngOnChanges` internally to catch changes of its input data. This means that modifying the arrays you have inputed to it will not trigger a change. And since your `barChartLabels` and `barChartData` array are already initialize as empty arrays, that is what the chart will use.

What you will need to do to trigger `ngOnChanges` is change the actual instances of `barChartLabels` and `barChartData` when you receive new data.

Replace this inside your `getData` method:

```
this.result.forEach( item => {
   this.barChartLabels.push(item.label);
   this.barChartData.push(item.dataInfo);
})
```

With something like this:

```
this.barChartLabels = this.result.map(item => item.label);
this.barChartDatat = this.result.map(item => item.dataInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I went ahead and applied what you suggested and i could see my data graph range has changed (it means it is actually going through) But my label is not being displayed on the graph - thus no colored bar appears.

Comment: i am looking through the plunker and i guess this means my issue is in the service somewhere when populating my array. I will try debugging with console.log statements and see what happens on my end. Hard coding does work for me i need to be importing them from a json

Comment: So i think the issue has to do with the ng2-charts canvas labels because i am not seeing any reason why this shouldn't work specially that the `barCharData` is appearing fine - oniine there is a lot on maybe changing some of the options for the canvas so i will be playing around with that but i will go ahead and mark this as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you log `this.barChartLabels` after it has been populated? To see what that data looks like @bluepearl

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post with where i added two console.logs along with their results to see.

Comment: @bluepearl well there is your answer - labels are not set. Please include your `dataService.getData()` code

Comment: I have included my get call in service file  in my post - I am able to see returned result after the call has been made in the service.

Comment: Also i have included console log for the data which shows same behavior as the labels but the data is reflected in the graph while the labels not. Also in the console the order in which the results are displayed are: `[ ]  [ ] All: [{"id":5,"label":"test 1","data":25},{"id":6,"label":"test 2","data":55}] ["test 1", "test 2"]  [22, 55]` it seems like the first pass the arrays are not initialized and then populated.

Comment: @bluepearl the empty console logs are appearing because you do a couple of logs outside (under) of your `subscribe`. They will be executed before your subscribe callback

Comment: This all seems really strange. I would love to help more, but I think the only way for me to do that would be if you could either put this up on github or reproduce in a plunker

Comment: I went a head and updated your plunker to be working using a service and displaying the graph - Plunker link in my original post. The graph does display a colored horizontal bar but it is not positioned properly and the labels are not appearing on the graph.

Comment: Here is a working example, by implementing a "loaded" flag. Does that work for you? https://plnkr.co/edit/xr6xs6PmaF9iQ6DsRnHT?p=preview @bluePearl

Comment: FINALLY!!!! IT IS WORKING AT LAAAAST!!!! You are AMAZING - Thank you a million for helping me out this long!

Comment: I think you should update your answer with the latest working plunker incase anyone runs through the same issue and looking for an answer.