# From JSON File: How to create one common angular ng2-charts (Bar chart) component which can be call from different components with different parameter

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am trying to create a common ng2-charts (Bar Stacked) component, where I can pass the data from other component and it will get update. Actually, I want to display multiple same stacked bar charts with different values in the same page while loading the page.

I have created one common component with ng-2 charts and created one service also. Now I am calling the common component from one more different component via shared service with different parameter and data source is coming from a json file which I am fetching via API.

Now, while fetching, when I am doing console.log()and in that, it is displaying my data.

**1st Situation:**

In my common component canvas html, if I write, 
**[datasets]="barChartData ? barChartData : []"**, 
then the **data is displaying** in the chart but in console, there are errors like
ERROR TypeError: "this.datasets[0] is undefined"
and for this error, everything get freezes, no other things work.

**2nd Situation,**

In my common component canvas html, if I write, 
**[datasets]="barChartData"**, then the **data is not displaying**"

my common component (bar-chart.component.ts),

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";

@Component({
  selector: "app-common-barchart",
  templateUrl: "./common-barchart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./common-barchart.component.css"]
})
export class CommonBarchartComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{}]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "center",
        align: "center"
      }
    }
  };

  @Input() barChartLabels: Label[];
  @Input() barChartData: ChartDataSets[];

  public barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];



  ngOnInit() {
    //console.log("barChartData", this.barChartData);
  }
}
```

my common component's html:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas
        baseChart
        height="400"
        [datasets]="barChartData ? barChartData : []"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the component, from which I am calling the common component, (department-wise-barchart.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { BarChartService } from "../../service/bar-chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-department-wise-barchart",
  templateUrl: "./department-wise-barchart.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./department-wise-barchart.component.css"]
})
export class DepartmentWiseBarchartComponent implements OnInit {
  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  public parentChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  public myLabelsArray: Label[];
  public barChartLabels: Label[];
  public isDataAvailable: boolean = false;

  constructor(private barchartservice: BarChartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barchartservice.getBarChartDataFromJSON("dept").subscribe(response => {
      this.parentChartData = response;
    });
  }
}
```

the corresponding html (employee-band-wise-barchart.component.html),

```
<app-common-barchart
  [barChartData]="parentChartData"
  [barChartLabels]="myLabelsArray"
></app-common-barchart>
```

the service file, (bar-chart.service.ts),

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BarChartService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private _url1: string = "../../assets/chart-dummy-data/emp-band.json";
  private _url2: string = "../../assets/chart-dummy-data/dept.json";

  getBarChartDataFromJSON(chartType): Observable<any> {
    if (chartType == "emp-band") {
      return this.http.get<any>(this._url1);
    } else if (chartType == "dept") {
      return this.http.get<any>(this._url2);
    } else {
      return this.http.get<any>(this._url2);
    }
  }  
}
```

my json file, (emp-band.json)

```
[
  {
    "data": [2, 5, 9],
    "label": "Male",
    "stack": "1"
  },
  {
    "data": [4, 1, 3],
    "label": "Female",
    "stack": "1"
  }
]
```

Can anybody please help me on this above situation.

NB: There will be multiple same type of component (with different data set) which will call the common component at the same time to display different parameterized data.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the above issue with the help of this **[ng2-charts bar graph not displaying data/graph labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675315/ng2-charts-bar-graph-not-displaying-data-graph-labels?rq=1)** url.

Instead of using the ternary operator (**[datasets]="barChartData ? barChartData : []"**) in the common component, if we use a flag (whether the data loaded or not, in my case, I have used a flag named "loaded") and using the flag in the calling componet's html like the below, then the above problem will get resolved.

```
<app-common-barchart
  *ngIf="loaded"
  [barChartData]="parentChartData"
  [barChartLabels]="myLabelsArray"
></app-common-barchart>
```